# Non-commutative abelian rings.

Tags: ring-theory, idempotents

Let $R$ be a ring with unity.

An element $e\in R$ is called **idempotent** if $e^2=e$. Clearly, $0,1$ are idempotents.

An element $e\in R$ is called **central** if $er=re$ for all $r\in R$.

Recall that a ring $R$ is called **abelian** if every idempotent is central.

Indeed, every commutative ring is abelian.

An example of noncommutative abelian ring is $k[x,y]$, where $k$ is any field and $xy\neq yx$. But the idempotents of $k[x,y]$ are the trivial idempotents $0$ and $1$.

My question is: Does there exist a noncommutative abelian ring with nontrivial idempotents?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just use $\mathbb H\times \mathbb H$ where $\mathbb H$ is Hamilton's quaternions.

Comment: Here's [another example](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=40&L=1&L=38) using the triangular ring construction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R = F\langle x, y \rangle$ be the free algebra with two variables over any field. Then $R$ has no nontrivial ideompotent. The ring $R\times R$ has four idempotents $\{0, 1\}\times\{0, 1\}$, and all of them are central.